# I have an ASP.net form on a website. I need to edit its actions based on the user selections, and make the radio button list allow multiple choices

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.net form on a website. I need to edit its actions based on the user selections, and make the radio button list allow multiple choices.

I have the compiled web application, all passwords and access, all files from the original build (I believe), Visual Studio 2010, and no idea what I'm doing.

The engineer who originally built the site has moved to India, and is no longer available.

I need to load this website as a project in Visual Studio. I need to find the form files. I need to edit the options, and the actions they produce.

Even pointing me in the direction of a way to learn what I need to know will help. If you need more information, tell me what you need.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the original source files (it sounds like you have them).  If it is a Web Site Project, then in Visual Studio you can do File -> Open -> WebSite and pick the directory containing those files; if it is a Web Application Project, then there should be a .csproj or a .vbproj file to open.

In order to allow the user to make multiple selections, you should use a checkbox list instead of radio buttons.

You can probably find more about ASP.NET on http://www.asp.net/get-started (I'd guess for your project that http://www.asp.net/web-forms is the first step to take).

Comment: How would I determine where the source files are? What I've found appears to be a compiled app. The developer claims we have everything, but he's no longer responding to contact requests...

Comment: As it turns out, I do have source files, just not in the same location I was looking at originally. There are no (apparent) project files, so I assume it is a website project. Is there a way to determine that for certain?

Comment: A website project will have 1 or 2 files for each form: foo.aspx and sometimes foo.aspx.cs (or .vb).  A web application project will aditionally have foo.aspx.designer.cs.  Also, a website will not have the intermediate build output directory (obj) though both will have the bin directory.  You can always try running it as a website project and see if it works. :)

Comment: So... Website project. Opened it as Website, got a message asking if I want to rebuild the solution file for Visual Studio 2010. Said yes. Now I have an apparently blank web project. There is no file explorer. If I go to Open a file, it opens into a new project folder with nothing in it except the .sln file. I can navigate to the folder where the files are stored, but every time I need a file, it starts me in that same project folder. Should I move the files there? Is this normal behavior? I am at the very beginning of learning here. I do appreciate your time and effort helping me out.